# NiFi - Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri

Tags: jdbc, hiveql, apache-nifi

I get this below error whenever I try to connect from NiFi to cloudera(5.16.2) hiveserver2, I have kerberos enabled and SSL enabled to hive service as well, the java version that hive runs is on OpenJDK and NiFi runs on Oracle JDK 1.8.162, the jdbc uri that I mention in the NiFi processor is " jdbc:hive2://hostname:10000/;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/data/nifi-1.10.0/tls/truststore.jks;principal=hive/hostname@AA.BBCC.NET

```
2020-06-11 10:03:34,853 INFO [NiFi Web Server-709] o.a.n.controller.StandardProcessorNode Starting PutHiveQL[id=734f0b34-d3fc-16bb-ffff-ffffeacb958f]
2020-06-11 10:03:34,853 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-8] o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent Scheduled PutHiveQL[id=734f0b34-d3fc-16bb-ffff-ffffeacb958f] to run with 1 threads
2020-06-11 10:03:34,857 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils Supplied authorities: hostname:10000
2020-06-11 10:03:34,857 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils Resolved authority: hostname:10000
2020-06-11 10:03:34,860 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection Will try to open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://hostname:10000/;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/data/nifi-1.10.0/tls/truststore.jks;principal=hive/hostname@AA.BBCC.NET
2020-06-11 10:03:34,861 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://hostname:10000/;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/data/nifi-1.10.0/tls/truststore.jks;principal=hive/hostname@AA.BBCC.NET
2020-06-11 10:03:34,861 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection Transport Used for JDBC connection: null
2020-06-11 10:03:34,862 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] o.a.nifi.dbcp.hive.HiveConnectionPool HiveConnectionPool[id=734f0b3c-d3fc-16bb-ffff-fffffcb9ca34] Error getting Hive connection: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://hostname:10000/;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/data/nifi-1.10.0/tls/truststore.jks;principal=hive/hostname@AA.BBCC.NET: Invalid status 21)
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://hostname:10000/;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/data/nifi-1.10.0/tls/truststore.jks;principal=hive/hostname@AA.BBCC.NET: Invalid status 21)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.hive.HiveConnectionPool.lambda$getConnection$0(HiveConnectionPool.java:369)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
        at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.hive.HiveConnectionPool.getConnection(HiveConnectionPool.java:369)
        at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPService.getConnection(DBCPService.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:87)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy227.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveQL.lambda$new$1(PutHiveQL.java:209)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.Put.onTrigger(Put.java:97)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveQL.lambda$onTrigger$6(PutHiveQL.java:295)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.PartialFunctions.onTrigger(PartialFunctions.java:114)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.RollbackOnFailure.onTrigger(RollbackOnFailure.java:184)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveQL.onTrigger(PutHiveQL.java:295)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1176)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:213)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
        at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://hostname:10000/;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/data/nifi-1.10.0/tls/truststore.jks;principal=hive/hostname@AA.BBCC.NET: Invalid status 21
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:231)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:176)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
        ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Invalid status 21
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.sendAndThrowMessage(TSaslTransport.java:232)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.receiveSaslMessage(TSaslTransport.java:184)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:277)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:52)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport.open(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:204)
        ... 37 common frames omitted
2020-06-11 10:03:34,862 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] o.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveQL PutHiveQL[id=734f0b34-d3fc-16bb-ffff-ffffeacb958f] org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveQL$$Lambda$960/419761608@2c9b9d46 failed to process due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://hostname:10000/;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/data/nifi-1.10.0/tls/truststore.jks;principal=hive/hostname@AA.BBCC.NET: Invalid status 21); rolling back session: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://hostname:10000/;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/data/nifi-1.10.0/tls/truststore.jks;principal=hive/hostname@AA.BBCC.NET: Invalid status 21)
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://hostname:10000/;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/data/nifi-1.10.0/tls/truststore.jks;principal=hive/hostname@AA.BBCC.NET: Invalid status 21)
        at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.hive.HiveConnectionPool.getConnection(HiveConnectionPool.java:384)
        at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPService.getConnection(DBCPService.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:87)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy227.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveQL.lambda$new$1(PutHiveQL.java:209)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.Put.onTrigger(Put.java:97)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveQL.lambda$onTrigger$6(PutHiveQL.java:295)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.PartialFunctions.onTrigger(PartialFunctions.java:114)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.RollbackOnFailure.onTrigger(RollbackOnFailure.java:184)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveQL.onTrigger(PutHiveQL.java:295)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1176)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:213)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
        at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://hostname:10000/;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/data/nifi-1.10.0/tls/truststore.jks;principal=hive/hostname@AA.BBCC.NET: Invalid status 21)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.hive.HiveConnectionPool.lambda$getConnection$0(HiveConnectionPool.java:369)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
        at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.hive.HiveConnectionPool.getConnection(HiveConnectionPool.java:369)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://hostname:10000/;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/data/nifi-1.10.0/tls/truststore.jks;principal=hive/hostname@AA.BBCC.NET: Invalid status 21
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:231)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:176)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
        ... 31 common frames omitted
```

Comment: this question is to hive/cloudera and not to nifi. search for [hive "Invalid status 21"](https://www.google.com/search?q=hive+%22Invalid+status+21%22)

Comment: @daggett: I have checked already in cloudera knowledge base and the solution that they have provided is to remove ssl=true and that didn't work either.cloudera has closed their ticket saying it's not supported as well.

Comment: I fixed this issue, by copying the truststore of Hive into Nifi folder where you keep the trust store and all the certs and then in the db connection pool i used the below connection string

jdbc:hive2://hive_hostname:10000/;principal=hive/hive_hostname@REALM;sslTrustStore=path-to-trust-store-of-hive;ssl=1;AuthMech=1;KrbRealm=REALM;KrbHostFQDN=hive_hostname;KrbServiceName=hive